# Are differentiable and strictly decreasing functions always concave?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

If a demand function is continuously differentiable  and strictly decreasing in price, does that mean it will be always concave?

Comment: I assume you mean convex, as in $f(x) = e^{-x}$? But even then is not true. The function may well be linear or concave in some parts, whereas its tail (towards infinity) is convex.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Neither convex, nor concave, think " smooth stairs".

$\bf{Added}$
Inspired by @Jack D'Aurizio: example
 $$\frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan( - x + \sin^2 x)$$.

[image]

Comment: Like $$e^{\sin x-x}\qquad\text{or}\qquad e^{-x^2}$$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: I like the $e^{\sin x - x}$ !

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $f(x)=e^{-x}$, which is convex everywhere and strictly decreasing.